# "task prioritizing" vs "task prioritization"

Tags: grammar

Let's suppose we want to list a manager's responsibilities. One of them is to prioritize tasks. This can be written in two ways:

Responsibilities of a manager:

- task prioritizing
- task prioritization

Is there any difference besides stylistic one? Which one is more appropriate?

Additional question. Should "task" be in plural form?

- tasks prioritizing
- tasks prioritization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a stylistic difference, and "prioritization" has a more formal sound, appropriate to a business document.

If you use "task prioritization", the word "task" must be singular. Another formal way to say it is "prioritization of tasks", where it must be plural.